# How to get bitrate in dash.js player while streaming the video?

Tags: mpeg-dash, mininet, dash.js

I am setting a dash Server in mininet and i want to store the bit rates by which video streams and also the quality of video chunks that dash server is sending in that bit rate. How would I get and store this all information in some file?

Answer (score 1):

The DASH.js player actually includes some event call-backs to handle this type of event.

Take a look at the source code on Github at dash.js/src/streaming/MediaPlayerEvents.js

```js
        /**
         * Triggered when an ABR up /down switch is initiated; either by user in manual mode or auto mode via ABR rules.
         * @event MediaPlayerEvents#QUALITY_CHANGE_REQUESTED
         */
        this.QUALITY_CHANGE_REQUESTED = 'qualityChangeRequested';

        /**
         * Triggered when the new ABR quality is being rendered on-screen.
         * @event MediaPlayerEvents#QUALITY_CHANGE_RENDERED
         */
        this.QUALITY_CHANGE_RENDERED = 'qualityChangeRendered';
```